# Ruby on Rails: Error when trying to add item to cart (using line items)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have three models:

Tracks, LineItems and Cart

By using line item associations, I'm adding tracks (for purchase) to a cart. Yet when I click 'add to cart' the following error message gets thrown:

`No route matches [POST] "/line_items/1"`

Despite extensively reviewing my code; I can't seem to find the problem, is it in my controller for line_items? It appears as though it is trying to post a line_item with id = 1 which doesn't exist?

line_items_controller.rb

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]

  # GET /line_items
  # GET /line_items.json
  def index
    @line_items = LineItem.all
  end

  # GET /line_items/1
  # GET /line_items/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /line_items/new
  def new
    @line_item = LineItem.new
  end

  # GET /line_items/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /line_items
  # POST /line_items.json
  def create
    @track  = Track.find(params[:track_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_track(track)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /line_items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /line_items/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.update(line_item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item, notice: 'Line item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /line_items/1
  # DELETE /line_items/1.json
  def destroy
    @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    @line_item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to cart_path(@cart), notice: 'Line item was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_line_item
      @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def line_item_params
      params.require(:line_item).permit(:track_id)
    end
end
```

carts_controller.rb

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with :invalid_cart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /carts
  # GET /carts.json
  def index
    @carts = Cart.all
  end

  # GET /carts/1
  # GET /carts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /carts/new
  def new
    @cart = Cart.new
  end

  # GET /carts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /carts
  # POST /carts.json
  def create
    @cart = Cart.new(cart_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @cart.save
        format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cart }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /carts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /carts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cart.update(cart_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @cart }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /carts/1
  # DELETE /carts/1.json
  def destroy
    @cart.destroy if cart.id == session[:cart_id] #hook into current client session instead of user
    session[:cart_id] = nil
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root-path, notice: 'Cart was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_cart
      @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def cart_params
      params.fetch(:cart, {})
    end

    def invalid_cart
      logger.error "Attempt to access invalid cart #{params[:id]}"
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "That cart doesn't exist"
    end
end
```

views > carts > show.html.haml

```
.keep-shopping.pv1.mt4.has-text-right
  = link_to 'Keep Shopping', tracks_path, class: 'button is-warning'
%hr/
%section.section
  = render(@cart.line_items)
  .columns
    .column
      = button_to 'Empty Cart', @cart, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure? " }, class: "button is-danger"
    .column.total.has-text-right
      %h4.title.is-4
        %span.f5.has-text-grey Total:
        = number_to_currency(@cart.total_price)
```

views > _line_items.html.haml (line helper partial)

```
.columns.align-items-center
  .column.is-1
    = line_item.quantity
  .column.is-2
    %figure.is-128x128.image
      = image_tag(line_item.track.image_url(:thumb))
  .column.is-9
    %strong= line_item.track.name
    .columns.align-items-center
      .content.column.is-9
        = truncate(line_item.track.description, length: 140)
      .column.is-3.has-text-right
        %strong.f4= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price)
.has-text-right
  = link_to 'Remove Item', line_item, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure? " }, class: "button is-small mb4"
= succeed "/" do
  %hr/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come across this issue before. I am most definitely from your "add to cart button". I suppose your LineItem belongs_to The Cart and the product. If so when you're passing your button data to your line_item "add to cart" button, you might wanna set the current cart also so that you send over both IDs.

If possible you might want to share more code snippets of your button and your relationships.

Comment: Glad i could share my experience